# Trying to decode zlib compressed and base64 encoded data to a readable format in Python

Tags: python-2.7, base64, compression, decode, zlib

```
import zlib, base64
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJxsvUuu7UizpNfXKG5PJUANP==))) 
###The code is short for example only
```

How can I decode this?
This is a picture of the code
https://prnt.sc/26xf8ju

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what issue you may be encountering, it should operate as normal. Always be careful when using `exec()` for things like this as it is used a lot by threat actors for running binaries.

```
import zlib, base64
a = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eF7zSM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU8FTPVcjPUwguSUzO9i9LLUrLyS9XBADJNQvD'))
print(a)
```

**Output:** b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!"