# How to encode the string in redable format

Tags: python

I have python code that decode and the decompress the string and when i encode and compress the string the ouput is different

```
import zlib, base64
a = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eF7zSM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU8FTPVcjPUwguSUzO9i9LLUrLyS9XBADJNQvD'))
print(a)
```

The output will be b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!"

```
a = zlib.compress(base64.b64encode(b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!"))
print(a)
```

but when i try to encode the above string b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!" the output i am getting is byte string like this `b'x\x9c\x0bv\x0f+Nr\xb7H\x0f3\xb2\xacLr\x0f\xcc\xf0t\xcd\xceK\nv*K\xcat\nIqw\xcbJ4\xb04\x8a\x8a\xf0\xcaMr\xb74\xf6\x0c\xb4\xb5\x05\x00\x85l\x0ff'`

but i want to get output like this eF7zSM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU8FTPVcjPUwguSUzO9i9LLUrLyS9XBADJNQvD

This was example from [Trying to decode zlib compressed and base64 encoded data to a readable format in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152281/trying-to-decode-zlib-compressed-and-base64-encoded-data-to-a-readable-format-in/73166990#73166990)

what is wrong in my code

Comment: The inverse of decompress(decode()) is encode(compress())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should look like

```py
import zlib, base64

compressed_data = zlib.compress(b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!")
encoded_data = base64.b64encode(compressed_data)

print(encoded_data)
print(encoded_data.decode())
```

---

```
b'eJzzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU8FTPVcjPUwguSUzO9i9LLUrLyS9XBADJNQvD'
eJzzSM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU8FTPVcjPUwguSUzO9i9LLUrLyS9XBADJNQvD
```

**Note:** Output is not exactly the same because compression algorithms are not guaranteed to produce same output for the same input.

Answer (score 1):

You should Base64 encode the result of compressing, not the other way around.

```py
print(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(b"Hello World! I'm on StackOverflow!")))
```